# Install a GUI on CentOS/Redhat 7 (smaller gui)

Tags: centos, redhat-enterprise-linux, gnome

I am using CentOS 7.3 install from "minimal installation".
I would like to have the Gnome GUI, if i install "Server with GUI" or "Gnome Desktop" i have a lot of packages which are useless for me... (libreoffice, weather, calculator and so on...).

There is a way to have a lightweight GUI Gnome with useful packages (gnome-terminal, etc..) ?

I want to install this GUI either with YUM or during installation with Kickstart.

Thanks

Comment: yum grouplist is your friend!

Comment: Yes, I know ! But if i install the group Server with GUI" or "Gnome Desktop" i have a lot of packages which are useless for me ! So maybe you can  tell me the name of a group which install a minimal GUI ?

Comment: If i do a `yum groupinstall gnome-desktop  x11  fonts`  they are too packages : libreoffice, and so on...